# Protractor: verify language icon has changed

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu, protractor

On the page there is a language switcher displayed as an icon. When I click on it, I get a list of countries with icon + country name. Now I'm randomly choosing the language, but I'm having troubles to verify the change as I cannot rely on the page translations.

HTML code:

```
<span uib-dropdown-toggle="" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <ng-transclude>
        <span class="change-language-icon"><img ng-src="/img/language_es.png" src="/img/language_es.png">
        </span>
    </ng-transclude>
</span>
```

Does anybody know how to verify if the above code changed to `/img/language_de.png` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that by extracting the `attribute - src` on the `img` element.Protractor API provide `webdriver.WebElement.getAttribute` method. Pls check [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) here

`expect(element(by.css('span.change-language-icon img')).getAttribute('src')).toEqual('/img/language_de.png')`